# Ключи от обеих ворот?

Tags: род, множественное-число

На Авито продают гараж с таким описанием:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ключи от *обеих* ворот или от *обоих* ворот? Или следует писать так: имеются ключи от обеих створок ворот?

Comment: "Обеих" относится только и исключительно к женскому роду: о створках - обеих, о воротах, если они не единственные, - обоих.

Comment: @behemothus пишет, что "от обеих ворот" и "от обоих ворот" нелигитимно. Но в любом случае это словосочетание вводит в заблуждение, ведь количество ворот в гараже 1, а не 2.

Comment: @М_Г behemothus-то пишет, но при этом  ссылается на источники, с которыми спорить сложнее. И да, речь только о нескольких экземплярах ворот. С одними воротами тут все достаточно очевидно.

Comment: @behemothus Для меня behemothus - тоже источник, заслуживающий доверия.

Comment: @ М_Г )))))))))))

Comment: На том и порешали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Есть ключи от обеих ворот или от обоих ворот?

Оба варианта ненормативны.

> Или следует писать так: ***имеются ключи от обеих створок ворот?***

Да, в случае, если речь идет именно о "створках". Но вообще-то у ворот не створки, а створы. Поэтому лучше будет ***"Имеются ключи от обоих створов ворот".***

Другой вопрос, если мы имеем **двое ворот**. 
Вроде бы, коль скоро ворот двое, то и обоих (обе формы - м. р.). Но вот тут возникают сложности.
Во-первых, сама такая форма "двое ворот" несвободна, хотя в современном языке признается почти всеми.

> В некоторых случаях для обозначения количества используются, наряду с
>   количественными числительными, также числительные собирательные (двое,
>   трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро). Двумя
>   последними числительными мы практически не пользуемся. Собирательные
>   числительные используются используются ограниченно, а именно:
>   ...
>   б) с существительными, имеющими формы только множественного числа: двое ножниц,
>   трое суток;

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=2.13

А во-вторых, в отличие от "двое" форма "оба"/"обе" в именительном падеже совершено не вяжется с множественным числом даже в просторечии.

> При употреблении собирательного числительного оба - обе в сочетаниях с
>   существительными женского рода в косвенных падежах используются формы
>   обеих, обеими, обеим и т. д. Эти числительные не употребляются с
>   существительными, не имеющими формы единственного числа, так как у них
>   отсутствует категория рода. ***Нельзя сказать у обоих ворот (нет формы
>   именительного падежа: оба - обе ворота), можно: у тех и у других
>   ворот.***

(там же, курсив мой - b-s)

Видимо, и косвенные падежи ("обоих"/"обеих") тут неприменимы, хотя они и меньше режут слух, чем именительный.

Так что фразу в любом случае надо править. 
Или ***"от обоих створов"*** или ***"от тех и (от) других ворот".***

Comment: У Кузнецова есть и створы ворот, и створки ворот. Возможно, зависит от размеров самих ворот (створ - створка больших размеров).

Comment: А почему _от обеих створов_, а не _от обоих створов_? https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/67129/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: @Уроборос Это опечатка, в первом случае правильно написал. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @М_Г А в каком месте? Тут нету "створок", только створы.  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&all=x

Comment: СТВОРКА, -и; мн. род. -рок, дат. -ркам; ж. 1. Закрывающаяся и открывающаяся часть или половина какого-л. предмета. Створки ставней, ворот http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Должно быть имелось ввиду: "Ворота бокса и ворота при въезде на территорию гаража открываются автоматически (с пульта). Есть ключи (пульты) от тех и других".

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что правильно использовать слово *воро́тина*: **ключи от обеих воротин.**

Предметы, обозначаемые словами *ворота, двери,* первоначально представляли целое, состоящее из двух частей (двухстворчатые двери или ворота). В соответствии с этим сингулятивы *воротина, дверина* обозначали одну створку ворот, двери, и в этом значении они употребляются в говорах до настоящего времени.
[В. Н. Мусатов. Сингулятивы в современном русском языке](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8NglDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=NGjUmZaoPz&sig=geEHPTI-PCSGizECNrjJEPJtq6g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi80NOOgI7eAhVEhaYKHQLpCmE4FBDoATAFegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false)

*Они останавливаются перед совсем уже феноменальными, как в паровозном
депо, воротами на ржавых пудовых петлях. (…) **На левой воротине** строго блестит толстым стеклом  солидная  синяя вывеска: "НИИЧАВО АН СССР. ИЗБА  НА  КУРИНЫХ  НОГАХ.  ПАМЯТНИК  СОЛОВЕЦКОЙ СТАРИНЫ".  **На  правой  воротине**  висит  ржавая  жестяная  табличка: "Ул. Лукоморье, д. N 13, Н. К. Горыныч", а под  нею  красуется  кусок  фанеры  с надписью чернилами вкривь и вкось: "КОТ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ. Администрация".*
[А. Стругацкий, Б. Стругацкий. Понедельник начинается в субботу (сценарий)](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/xussr_s/strug&49.htm?1/7)

*Для тех, кто понимал, ворота школы представляли собой потрясный и, главное, бесплатный аттракцион почище качелей или там каруселей.

Надо было отвязать цепочку **на любой из воротин,** потом разбежаться немного, оттолкнуться и встать обеими ногами на нижнюю перекладину железной скрепляющей рамы, уцепиться руками за прутья и – поехали!*
[Л. Матвеева. Бабка Поля Московская](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=61884&p=94)

У нашей семье есть гараж, поэтому слово **воротина** мы используем частенько.

Comment: Вот это находка! В словарях либо ничего, либо какая-то ерунда (воротина=воротища=ворота),  но в Нацкорпусе — 23 вхождения, именно как половинка ворот.

Answer (score 0):

Ворота же одни? Просто: ключи от ворот.

Comment: Но створки-то две. Я это не с головы беру, так написано в объявлении о продаже гаража, ворота которого требуют, насколько я понимаю, два ключа.